# Using Nested Paging for Application-Level Paging

Tags: x86, paging, virtualization

I'm not too familiar with the Nested Paging virtualization feature of newer CPUs, and so this question might not be a great question, but I've thought of an idea:

Is it possible to use nested paging in our applications to enable our own kind of paging mechanism (something like memory-mapped files)?

This could allow you to redirect memory accesses from anywhere the application to anywhere else, even if you don't have access to the code you're redirecting. (It wouldn't even require mapping to files, though -- you could produce the data on the fly, when the page fault happens.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's feasible. I don't know the details, but I think setting up the nested page tables would have to be done in hypervisor mode, which is even more privileged than kernel mode. To make use of it in user mode you'd need to have a hypervisor running which provided some sort of API to user mode (or to kernel mode, which then provided it to user mode). It wouldn't be a simple matter of using some extended CPU instructions from a user-mode application. I doubt that the gains would justify the effort required.

Edit: it sounds like I am right. Quoting from [AMD-V™ Nested Paging white paper](http://developer.amd.com/assets/NPT-WP-1%201-final-TM.pdf), 
Section 4.2.3: "Using Nested Paging":

> Nested paging is a feature intended for hypervisor’s use. The guest 
>   cannot observe any difference (except performance) while running 
>   under a hypervisor using nested paging. Nested paging does not 
>   require any changes in guest software.

Comment: That doesn't make sense... VirtualBox uses Nested Paging but it has nothing to do with Hypervisor mode (right?).

Comment: @Mehrdad: All I know is that when I install it I have to click through lots of warnings about unsigned kernel-mode drivers.

Comment: @Hugh: Wait, but how can you start a hypervisor *after* Windows starts? That doesn't make sense to me..

Comment: @Mehrdad: OK I did some reading and added a reference to support my uninformed speculation :)

Comment: @Hugh: Huh, interesting, thanks. :) But the question still stays: How can VirtualBox possibly start its own hypervisor *after* Windows starts? Even if the hypervisor was stable (which I doubt, since VB itself is barely stable, let alone such a critical component), it can't possibly start *after* the OS, can it? (And it's not like it loads before the OS loader, so...)

Comment: @Mehrdad: "VB itself is barely stable" - why do you say this? In my experience it doesn't crash more than VMWare.

Comment: @Hugh: I wasn't saying VMWare was any better (I haven't used it in a while), but that VB is nowhere near stable enough as a regular VM to now be taking a leap and making a hypervisor. VB frequently freezes on me with an Ubuntu guest (not reproducible, kind of random), and it also crashes on me with Windows 7 guest when I try to turn on 3D acceleration (reproducible). Wasn't trying to blame VB, just mentioning the fact that it's pretty unlikely they install a hypervisor-like thing on a Windows machine, especially when it's already running.